# ¿Como puedo validar permisos por mes?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Estoy tratando de hacer una validación que solo me permita registrar 2 permisos por mes, es decir después de los dos permisos mensuales, ya no pueda realizare ningún otro permisos si no hasta el próximo mes.

Tengo mi siguiente código:

```
var contadormensual = response.data.length;

              if(contadormensual >= 2){
                  this.desabilitado = 1;
              }

              else{
                  this.desabilitado = 0;
              }
```

Comment: y cual seria el problema con este codigo?

Comment: Quieres hacer la validación en front-end o back-end?

Comment: @HCK en  front-end